# Adding color mapping through a seperate data frame in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot densities.
I have the following data frame:

```
> head(plotdat)
  Var1       Var2    value
1    1 K4me2_ChIP 3.584963
2    2 K4me2_ChIP 5.247928
3    3 K4me2_ChIP 5.700440
4    4 K4me2_ChIP 6.357552
5    5 K4me2_ChIP 5.832890
6    6 K4me2_ChIP 4.392317
```

I plot densities in this way:

```
> ggplot(data = plotdat) + geom_density(aes(x = value)) +
+ facet_wrap(~ Var2)
```

[image]

I have an additional DataFrame that contains the following:

```
> head(colD[,c(1,2)])
DataFrame with 4 rows and 2 columns
                 Sample        type
            <character> <character>
K4me2_ChIP   K4me2_ChIP        ChIP
K4me2_input K4me2_input       input
K4me3_ChIP   K4me3_ChIP        ChIP
K4me3_input K4me3_input       input
```

Now I'd like to color the density plots according to the 'type' column in the second data frame, so the two plots on the left get one color and the ones on the right the other.

I could do it be adding a additional column to the 'plotdat' data.frame which contains the mapping specified by 'type' in the second data frame as an additional column, is this the best way to go?

Comment: Yes, merging the data is the best way to go. Ggplot works best when each datapoint is one one line with all information regarding that datapoint on the same line (eg, long data)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to add the column to my plotdat:

```
idx <- match(plotdat$Var2, colD$Sample)
plotdat$type <- factor(colD$type[idx])
```

Then to plot it:

```
ggplot(data=plotdat) + geom_density(aes(x=value, fill=type)) + facet_wrap(~ Var2)
```